# JS Part not being run on IE / Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm having a function and an on-click event on a button. The function writes data from an xmlhttprequest into a container. This works when the page is reloaded, so there doesn't appear to be any problem.

Then I have a button that writes data (also via xmlhttprequest) into some DB. On successful post the above-mentioned function is being called. This should then fill the container with the full dataset again.

This is the function

```
var refreshSearchCriteriaStorage = function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('search_storage_list');

    if (container === null) {
        return;
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', '/wp-content/plugins/oshcr/run-ajax.php?call=search-criteria-listing', true);
    request.onload = function() {
        container.style.display = 'none';
        container.style.overflow.y = 'scroll';

        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            if (data.count === undefined || data.storage === undefined) {
                container.innerHTML = '<li>Error fetching criteria. Please try reloading the site.</li>';
                container.style.display = 'block';

                return;
            }

            container.innerHTML = '';

            data.storage.forEach(function(entry) {
                container.insertAdjacentHTML(
                    'beforeend',
                    '<li><a href="/search-results/?' + entry.query + '">' + entry.title + '</a></li>'
                );
            });

            if (data.storage.length < 1) {
                container.innerHTML = '<li>You have no saved search criteria yet.</li>';
            }

            container.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            if (debugMode) {
                console.log(response);
            }

            container.innerHTML = '<li>Error fetching criteria. Please try reloading the site.</li>';
            container.style.display = 'block';
        }

        container.style.display = 'block';
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
        if (debugMode) {
            console.debug(response);
        }

        container.innerHTML = '<li>Error fetching criteria. Please try reloading the site.</li>';
        container.style.display = 'block';
    };
    request.send();
};
```

And this is the button on-click event

```
/**
 * Save Search Criteria
 */
$('#save_search_criteria').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var criteriaTitle = $('#search_criteria_title').val();

    if (criteriaTitle === undefined || criteriaTitle.trim() === '') {
        alert("Please input a title for this search criteria\nThis way you will be able to quickly find your results again.");

        return false;
    }

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/wp-content/plugins/oshcr/run-ajax.php?call=save-search-criteria', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    request.onload = function() {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            if (debugMode) {
                console.debug(request.response);
            }

            document.getElementById('search_criteria_title').innerHTML = '';

            refreshSearchCriteriaStorage();

            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

            if (data.message !== undefined) {
                alert(data.message);
            }
        } else {
            if (debugMode) {
                console.debug(request.response);
            }
        }
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
        if (debugMode) {
            console.debug(request.response);
        }
    };

    request.send(
           'title=' + criteriaTitle
        + '&query=' + $('#searchResultsForm').serialize()
    );
});
```

On initial page reload the function is simply called via

```
refreshSearchCriteriaStorage();
```

Now when I click the button the data is successfully being written into the backend. However the `refreshSearchCriteriaStorage()` appears to not be called. No additional request is being fired, nor does the content of the container change.

And this ONLY happens in IE / Edge. I'm really lost on this. So any input is appreciated.

You may argue that I should just append the list via JS dynamically, however the result comes back ordered. So it's kind of a lazy thing - it still makes no sense to me though that it only doesn't work in Microshit browsers and all others will do it just fine.